# Why does gradle have 1:1 mapping with android studio versions

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Recently I upgraded `Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7` to `Android Studio 3.0 RC 1`. The dependancies in build.gradle also got changed from `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-rc1'`

Gradle is a build tool managed by entirely separate organization, separate community. Then how come gradle make their releases with android studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, `gradle` does not have 1:1 mapping with android studio versions. There is no relationship between gradle and android studio versions.

`com.android.tools.build:gradle` is a gradle plugin for Android developed by Google team.From [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle), you can see the plugin requires gradle version.For example, if the plugin version is `2.3.0+`, you should use gradle whose version is `3.3+`.In addition, you can check gradle version in `rootProject/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

In your case, you can also downgrade `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'` to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-rc1'` and it can works. However different plugin version, different performance.